# Conditional PDF given a random variable theory

Tags: random-variable, conditional-probability, continuous-data

I am trying to understand the derivation of the formula for a conditional pdf given another random variable, but I am unsure if my interpretation is correct. I am following the course from MIT - Introduction to Probability by John Tsitsiklis. Here is the specific video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kj6iEzXsFkI&t=323s

For a discrete random variable we can calculate the conditional PMF using:

$p_{X\lvert Y}(x\lvert y) = P(X=x \lvert Y=y) =  \frac{p_{X,Y}(x,y)}{p_{Y}(y)}$

Now in the continuous case $P(x \leq X \leq x + \delta  \lvert Y=y)$ is problematic as $P(Y=y) = 0$. Hence we must condition on a small interval around $y$ rather than a specific $y$ value. Hence our conditional probability becomes the probability that $X$ falls in a small interval $\delta$ around $x$ given that $Y$ fell in a small interval $\epsilon$ around $y$. In terms of densities, this is approximately equivalent to the joint density of X and Y evaluated at a specific $x$ and $y$ multiplied by the area $\delta \epsilon$ divided by the marginal distribution of $Y$ evaluated at a specific $y$
multiplied by the interval $\epsilon$.

$P(x \leq X \leq x + \delta \lvert y \leq Y \leq y + \epsilon) \approx \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)\delta \epsilon}{f_{Y}(y)\epsilon} = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)\delta}{f_{Y}(y)}$

The $\epsilon$ cancels out and we are left with the joint pdf $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ divided by the marginal pdf $f_{Y}(y)$ multiplied by the interval $\delta$.

Does this imply that we are dividing the joint density by the marginal density evaluated at specific $x$ and $y$ values (without any intervals) and then integrating over $dx$? In other words, we can just divide the joint density function by the marginal density function and then integrate over $dx$?

Answer (score 1):

The conditional density of $X$ given $Y$ is defined almost everywhere as
$$f_{X|Y}(x|y)=\dfrac{f_{XY}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}$$This means that for a measurable set A and almost every $y$
$$\mathbb P(X\in A|Y=y)=\int_A \dfrac{f_{XY}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}\,\text dx$$
which satisfies the marginal equation
$$\mathbb E^Y[\mathbb P(X\in A|Y)] = \mathbb P(X\in A)$$
(also seen as the rigorous way to define conditional distributions).